# What are the incentives for career prosecutors and assistant Attorney Generals/US Attorneys?

Tags: united-states, lawyer

Are they out to get the highest number of convictions per attempt?  Are they out to get the highest total number of convictions?  Do they get evaluated based upon maximizing revenues?  Are they lauded for getting the most amount of prisoners as possible?  What gets you ahead in that career path?  (And I am wondering if the incentive structure might be perverse in some way; that's why I am asking.)

Comment: Interesting question, however, I'm voting to close it as off-topic because it should be asked on the politics.stackecxange.com site.

Comment: First and basically, clearing all cases assigned to them, second, getting convictions in every case and preventing them from ever being reversed, third, getting long sentences when possible, fourth, developing good relationships with law enforcement, fifth, successfully handling complex and high press profile projects that are the DA or U.S. Attorney for the district's priority (e.g. a major bank fraud case or organized crime ring). Revenues and materiality of the offenses or only convicting actually guilty people or prison costs incurred or appropriateness of sentence are mostly irrelevant.